# Error running timer: (void-function helm-completion--flex-transform-pattern)

Tags: helm, helm-for-files

Since a recent packages update (and still with the latest `helm` version 20220114), (almost) each time I try to use `helm-for-files`, I get the following error:

> Error running timer: (void-function helm-completion--flex-transform-pattern)

I must admit I have a lot of packages installed but I'd like to know what's the culprit.

BTW, I enabled `toggle-debug-on-error` but can't provide the `backtrace` since it appears while I'm typing something in the mini-buffer and disappears if I try to select and copy the content of its buffer.

Comment: `M-x list-timers` will give you a list of timers running in your Emacs.  Knowing what each of them runs might get you closer to the culprit. If you can't guess which timer might cause the problem, maybe you can start Emacs without `helm` and see what timers *it* is running: comparing with the other list might narrow things down to one timer (or a few). Unfortunately debugging is hard and remote debugging is almost impossible, so these are only suggestions for small steps that might help: good luck!

Comment: Nothing new appears when running `helm-for-files` after `M-x list-timers`.

Comment: What does `(featurep 'helm-mode)` return? If it says `nil`, add `(require 'helm-mode)` to your init file. If it says `t`, then see if the "missing" function is now defined. It's possible that `helm-mode` is not loaded to begin with and the timer calls it, getting the error. When eventually `helm-mode` *is* loaded, the function is now defined and the error goes away.

Comment: @NickD `(featurep 'helm-mode)` returns `nil` and adding `(require 'helm-mode)` to my init file seems to do the trick! :) Would you make your comment into an answer in order I can accept it?

Comment: Sure - glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in a comment, it seems that a timer gets started that calls `helm-completion--flex-transform-pattern` but the function is not defined yet. The function is defined in `helm-mode.el[c]` and that file provides the feature `helm-mode`: when the OP tested for the feature with `(featurep 'helm-mode)`, the return value was `nil` indicating that the file was not loaded yet, so the function was undefined. So the solution is to make sure that the file is loaded at initialization, before the timer gets started.

To do that, one has to add

```el
(require 'helm-mode)
```

in the Emacs initialization file, ideally before the timer gets set up, but the details of which timer it is and how it gets set up have not been clarified, so the safest thing to do is to add the `require` fairly early in the initialization file.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.
I found that, after the helm package update, helm.el was missing.
Downloading helm from [github](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/archive/refs/tags/v3.8.0.zip) and simply placing helm.el in my emacs.d/elpa/helm directory solved the issue for me. Well, solved it as far as I can notice.

Comment: I haven't any `.emacs.d/elpa/helm` directory. But I have, in the directory `.emacs.d/elpa/helm-core-20220104.1344`, a `helm.el` file which is identical to the one in the GitHub `helm`'s repo.

Comment: sorry, I cut and pasted it wrong, helm.el is in my .emacs.d/elpa/helm-20220114.658/ 
If files are identical then I'm not sure if I can help you. Maybe open a new issue on helm github account https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a bug in helm, now fixed - see [this commit](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/b9acaecbc05970b9c85eff8f2898b2410066bac6) and the linked issue.